# AWS dynamodb over AWS S3

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AWS and need to decide what to choose between AWS dynamo db or AWS S3.

I have a use case in which I need to fetch multiple items from the data source and update the items and put back to the data source. I have searched and found that we can't perform multiple get in S3.

Any Suggestions it will be helpful !!

Comment: you need to provide more details for anyone to be able to help you

Answer (score 18):

AWS Dynamodb and S3 serves different purposes.

Dynamodb - Is good for storing structured or semi-structured data. Its has limits in storage size(Record should be less than 400KB's) but has very high access speeds (Single digit millisecond)

S3 - Is good for storing files. Files could be read over http with its REST API. It allows to store very large files(Up to 5 TB's) with a reasonable access speeds.

For some requirements both services can be used together.
e.g.
If you need store user profiles with profile image, you can upload the image to S3 and store the link in user profiles table in dynamodb as an attribute.

Answer (score 8):

I have used both Dynamodb and S3. 
It depends on your application and type of data, if you are going to use that for real time application i would suggest Dynamodb. Latency is good on dynamodb compare to s3 and you can update data based on your key. If you are going to update images or some kind of files you can use s3 and you can save some money with s3.

Answer (score 4):

While I understand, that you want to do CRUD operations (create, read , update and delete) - it is crucial to understand the following factors to decide whether S3 or dynamoDB fits your use-case.
[1]Data Structure ->  Are you storing objects as whole like documents or tuples of data ?
[2]Evolution of Data -> How frequent your data will get updated?
[3]Concurrency -> How many concurrent reads or writes at a time? How many clients will be reading and writing the data store?
[4]Scalability -> does your use-case involves billions of objects which needs to be retrieved in a sub-second response time ??

AWS S3 is a scalable storage service which not only helps to store the data in a secure & organization way but also helps to manage its lifecycle though other storage classes like IA and glaciers in a cost efficient way.

AWS DynamoDB is a NOSQL storage service, which gives you a high concurrency reads/writes (which you can provision) as per your need and you need to pay only for those reads/writes. With primary & secondary (local or global) indexes, highly distributed cluster pattern can be obtained for sub-second response queries.

In some ways, you can also use both S3 and DynamoDB together by fronting Lambda services distributing your compute requirements across these storage services. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I actually did a similar kind of experiment and I would say that DynamoDB is the best choice because it has very fast read and write speeds than S3.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on updating items regularly then it's best to use DynamoDB. DynamoDB will be able to update and delete records faster than S3. S3 has many facilities (backups) with your files in case your bucket gets corrupted or deleted. However, it takes time for updates and deletes to be visible in S3. So, if the S3 bucket is regularly updated, then you risk customers seeing information that was not meant to be seen. Only use S3 if you want an easy way to upload files and download them with minimal need of deleting and updating, or don't care if users see old data. Summary: writes and reads are instant in S3. Updates and deletes take time to propagate across facilities.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamodb is very fast and you can expect predictable performance.  If your requirement is performance oriented then go for dynamodb.  Also you can query/scan the data based on requirement.

If your require more storage space and file read through REST then go for S3.  S3 is cheaper than dynamodb.  Also you can set life cycle policy for files which you not accessing frequently.

Answer (score 0):

For use cases like the one you described you go with DynamoDB.

However there is an exception to that.

The maximum item size in DynamoDB is 400 KB. So in case of items bigger than 400KB then it is recommended to store part of the information on S3 and add an attribute, to reference the s3 item, to your dynamodb entry. 
For concurrent updates you can use a conditional update or apply a counter.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you DynamoDb instead of S3, Dynamodb works on key value pair like as hashmap if you are searching the data from dynamodb using correct key(partition key or index) then searching will be extremely fast otherwise dynamo will scan the complete table and you may also face the provisioned throughput exception if your data in table in high or provisioned read capacity is low.

1 read capacity means 4KB data fetching per seconds, while scanning of data high provisioned rate is need when your data in table is quite high.

Please use dynamo in such way that data should be completely indexed means you have to search data using partition and range key so that scanning can be avoided.

Each read and write throghput cost several dollars .

Answer (score 0):

`Amazon S3` is an object storage capable of storing very large objects. `S3` is typically used for storing files like images,logs etc. `DynamoDB` is a `NoSQL` database that can be used as a **key value** (schema less record) store. For simple data storage, `S3` is the cheapest service. 
`DynamoDB` has the better performance, low cost and higher scalability and availability.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamodb is meant for Metadata, It is extremely fast when you are searching based on key as internally it is using hashing in order to find the item in collection(Table). But its read and write operations are dependent on provisioning throughput. 1 read throughput means that you can read 4Kb of data per sec and 1 write throughput mean that you can write 1Kb of data per sec. More the throughput capacity more will be cost in aws.

Hence I will suggest to use Dynamodb in case when you are querying the data based on key not at all recommended for scanning the data without key(you will be getting throughput exception).

S3 is object based storage like disk not a database, data will be there in buckets you can search but read after update is always very slower in S3.